# Правильно ли реализована карта на сайте? А также radio-кнопки?

Tags: html, css3

http://ip.16mb.com/pub/nerds/

Подскажите имеет ли право на жизнь данный код?

Также был бы благодарен за критику верстки в общем.

ps.я не волшебник, я только учусь.

Comment: что подразумевается под "правильно" ?

Comment: В принципе таким ли образом карту помещают на сайт.
Или, возможно, лучше реализовать ее по другому.

Comment: мне кажется, что как считает создатель/заказчик сайта, так и есть правильно и однозначного ответа тут нет :)

Comment: Возможно :)
Но так как создатель учится, а заказчик отсутствует пока в принципе, считаю нужным и полезным спросить\посоветоваться у более опытных людей.
Землякам отдельный привет)

Comment: заказчик сам скажет, где он хочет, чтобы была карта, кнопки меню и т.д.

Comment: А работать оно не должно?

Comment: Слайдер - пока нет, карта должа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно. Оба раза.

1. Карта. В зависимости от разрешения монитора маркер на карте показывает в разные точки. То есть нет никакой привязки маркера к реальной точке на карте. Карту такого типа необходимо встраивать таким образом (тут же можно посмотреть как делать маркер в виде картинки) https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage
2. Уверен, что радио-кнопки тут подразумеваются как переключатель слайдера. Пример - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/animated-blocks/ Сейчас в вашей верстке в кнопках нет никакого смысла.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и  ссылки.
Обязательно сейчас прочту.